# Saving large SVGs from svg elements

Tags: javascript, svg

I have a graphing script which uses svg elements to draw the graphs (no libraries just JS). I prefer using canvas but I am using svg to allow more straightforward export as SVG.

I am currently putting the svg element into an img tag and then saving it, e.g.:

```
<img src='data:image/svg+xml;base64,[base64 encoded svg element here]'>
```

Everything works for small graphs. The problem is that some of the graphs, in particular scatter plots, have 30k+ elements. Whether I use base64 encoding or just the svg xml in the img src attribute, the image appears in the browser, but does not download. I get a "Failed - Network error" in Chrome when I try to save the image to file.

I can think of alternatives, but they are all pretty annoying (such as producing the SVG on the server rather than in the browser). So first of all I wanted to see if there is some simple solution, such as compression, or a "browser-side" alternative to the method I am using above.

Comment: Why are you base-64 encoding this in the first place?  That adds a significant overhead.  You can either inject the markup directly into your document, or put it into a blob and use a blob URL as the image source.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/svg

Comment: @Brad can you elaborate on the blob solution? In general I wasn't using base64 but just putting the svg xml into the img src attribute, which as I said worked fine for small graphs but doesn't work for large graphs. The base64 encoding isn't the issue.

Comment: Can you show your code where you're generating the XML?

Comment: @Brad aye, the blob solved the issue